# NameError: name 'disney_total_revenue' is not defined

Tags: python, function, jupyter-notebook

I'm having problem running the function after importing from a script file to ipynb.  Can someone help me on what i'm missing here?  I have attached the image of the error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUY5U.png)
If i run the same function within ipynb, i get the results:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djOvu.png)

Comment: Please read [why you should not upload images of text when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

All good.  py file not in the same folder.